# logstash - drop events with date field not from specific date

Tags: ruby, logstash

I want to drop events, which have field `createdTm` not from specific date.
`createdTm` is received as `long` (time from epoch) and then I convert it to date.

Actual not working configuration:

```
date {
match => [ "createdTm", "UNIX_MS" ]
target => "createdTm"
}

if !("2017-09-14" in [createdTm]) { drop {} }
```

But this seems to drop everything.

I have seen some ruby codes, which use current time and calculate difference, but it is not what i want, because if run shortly after midnight, it would accept logs from yesterday too.

I am using logstash 2.3.
Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up "hacking" it as so:

```
mutate {
        convert => { "createdTm" => "integer" }
    }

if !([createdTm]>=1505433600000 and [createdTm]<=1505519999000) {
    drop {}
}

date {
        match => [ "createdTm","UNIX_MS" ]
    target => "createdTm"
}
```

Firstly I convert `createdTm` to integer, to be able to compare it.
Next, I compare it to those constant values, which are also miliseconds from unix epoch (1970) - basically to check if `createdTm` is in interval.
If not, drop event, if it is, convert it to date and continue message parsing.

I say "hacky", because I need to get those constant values in some online converters and its not really intuitive.
I havent find option to parse date first and then check it as string, as mentioned in question.